# A subspace is the direct sum of two others

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $W,W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$. Under what conditions we have $W=(W\cap W_1)\oplus(W\cap W_2)$ ?

this was the firs problem of our exam. does anyone know what is the answer to this problem?

Comment: Could you clarify please?  Are you asking under what conditions on $W$ do we have $W = (W \cap W_1) \oplus (W \cap W_2)$?

Comment: I wrote exactly the question's statement. I don't know what condition was in mind of our teacher.

Answer (score 2):

Either one of the following conditions is sufficient:

1. $W=U_1+ U_2$ for some subspaces $U_1\subseteq W_1$ and $U_2\subseteq W_2$
2. $\dim W=\dim(W\cap W_1)+\dim(W\cap W_2)$ (if $\dim W$ is finite)